# Two email sent from wordpress and woocommerce after register? how to prevent?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

My shopping website is created by WordPress and WooCommerce. When user registers in website, two emails are sent to user, one from WooCommerce and one from WordPress. How can I prevent WordPress from sending the email? I just need woo commerce send the register successful email.

Comment: Have you tried a search engine?
I have found a lot of results with Lilo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php' which will disable both user & admin notifications.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_new_user_notification' ) ) :
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $deprecated = null, $notify = '' ) {
        return;
    }
endif;
```